# MYSQL Average over day statististics

Tags: mysql, statistics, aggregate-functions

Use Case: I have a cron checking **every 5 minutes** some statistics and insert it into the database table **stats**

```
**Structure**

`time` as DATETIME   (index)

`skey` as VARCHAR(50)  (index)

`value` as BIGINT

Primary (time and skey)
```

Now I want to create a graph to display the daily average in progress over the day - so i.E. a graph for playing users:

```
from 0-1 i have 10 playing users (avg value from 0-1 is now 10)
from 1-2 i have 6 playing users (avg value is now 8 =>  (10+6) / 2)
from 2-3 i have 14 playing users (avg value is no 10 => (10+6+14) / 3
```

and next day it begins from start

I got already queries running, but it takes 3.5+ seconds to run

First attempt:

```
SELECT *  
     , (SELECT AVG(value) 
          FROM stats as b 
         WHERE b.skey = stats.skey 
           AND b.time <= stats.time 
           AND DATE(b.time) = DATE(stats.time)) 
  FROM stats 
 ORDER 
    BY stats.time DESC
```

Second attempt:

```
SELECT *
     , (SELECT AVG(b.value) 
          FROM stats as b 
         WHERE b.skey = stats.skey 
           AND DATE(b.time) = DATE(stats.time) 
           AND b.time <= stats.time) as avg 
  FROM stats 
 WHERE skey = 'playingUsers' 
 GROUP 
    BY HOUR(stats.time)
     , DATE(stats.time)
```

First try was to get each entry and calculate the average

Second try was to group by hour (like my example)

Anyway, this does not change anything in performance

Is there anyway to boost performance in mysql or do i have to change the full logic behind it?

DB Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/krFmR1yPsmnPny2zi5NJGv/4

Comment: I think step one should be to construct a credible query. Nothing above remotely fits that bill. See See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I fear we have differing interpretations of the word 'minimal' (as well as '3')

Comment: well i removed now the unused stats.. only playingUsers inside, but i guess the amount of data is needed to show it is going extremly slow.

Comment: I recreated the indexes.. not its from 3.5seconds down to 1.7 but still slow i guess

Comment: No. This community is quite capable of providing scalable queries- once it understands what's actually required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to separate the calculation of the average per hour from the calculation of the days average and to calculate these values only once per hour via grouping.

If you are on MySQL 8, I suggest to use CTE as follows:

```sql
with HOURLY AS (
    SELECT distinct
                    DATE_,
                    HOUR_,
                    AVG(b.value) as avg_per_hour
    FROM (SELECT s.value, DATE(s.time) DATE_, HOUR(s.time) HOUR_
          FROM stats s
          where skey = 'playingUsers'
         ) b
    GROUP BY b.DATE_, b.HOUR_
    ORDER BY b.DATE_ DESC, b.HOUR_ DESC
)
SELECT *
     , (SELECT AVG(b.avg_per_hour)
        FROM HOURLY as b
        WHERE b.DATE_ = HOURLY.DATE_
          AND b.HOUR_ <= HOURLY.HOUR_) as avg
FROM HOURLY
```

This statement lasts < 300 ms in the given fiddle.

The calculation corresponds to the algorithm you described in the table above.

However, the results differ from those of the statements presented.

Comment: @Kapsonfire can you confirm my test result with the hole amount of data.
Furthermore, I suggest, for better scaling, to implement a kind of paging mechanism in your presentation logic, so that you could limit the resultset to a certain range of time. Maybe putting the Date and Hour calculation to "generated stored fields" and further index optimizations such as a "covering index" gives a further acceleration.

Comment: i use maria db 10.1 - CTE isnt supported yet, will try it with a snapshot in some days, but thanks for mentioning CTE